# Talend tJava customCode "cannot be resolved to a type" with tLibraryLoad

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, talend

I am trying to follow [this tutoria](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/5.6+tLibraryLoad)l with my own jar file :

[image: package]

TSVTransposer is the main if this matters in some way.

I exported this package using the eclipse exporter as a jar file.

This is my Job in Talend :

[image: Job]

This is my code in the tJava : 
[image: TjavaCode]

With InputFile being one of my own Java class.

And this is my tLibraryLoad :

[image: tLibraryLoad]

When I try to run the job, I get this error :

[image: error]

As if my jar hadn't been imported at all.

Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Advanced settings` of the **tJavaRow** component, add

```
import my.package.path.to.tsvTranspositer.*;
```

This will be added to the generated Java code and make your class available to the job.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and post the result. Ty for the answer!

Comment: `import tsvTranspositer.*; ` worked. 

In which case would I have needed to add the path? When is there a path? I don't know if I am clear.

Comment: That would be the case if you use [packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/), which is almost always the case to structure the code.